# Conservation of energy issue with pair creation/annihilation

Tags: energy-conservation, pair-production

Question: what is the energy balance in this situation?

(Fig A)
Two gamma rays collided and produced an electron/positron pair  $(e-/e+)$.

(Fig B)
 1. because all particles are accelerating electromagnetic energy
    (photons) were radiated and spread away.
 2. they evolved and nearby neutral/charged particles were set in motion due to the
    gravitational/electrostatic field of the particles.
 3. an electron $e-$ and a positron $e+$ pair got annihilated and gamma rays produced.

(Fig C)
 4. Further away more neutral/charged particles were set in motion due to the propagating gravitational/electric (previously originated by the e+, e- pair).
 5. Further away more neutral/charged particles were set in motion due to …
 6. …
    Further away more neutral/charged particles were set in motion ..

### Conlusion: all universe is set in motion at the expense of a bit of energy ?

Questions:
  Q1 - how can the e+/e- pair have the same energy content in the beginning and at end of situation B) when, admittedly, the kinetic energy of the pair can be as little as we wish?
   Q2 – how to evade from situation C ? (I admit that the electromagnetic/gravitational field do propagate and cannot be set to null instantly)

[image: pair/production/annihilation]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics)

My comments:

For fig A:

Photon photon collisions are not the primary creators of particle pairs, but granted it is a possibility in the very dense matter of the early universe.

For fig. B:

Once created they move on a geodesic  without acceleration with the momentum given from the balance in the local area of the interaction. Why would they accelerate?
To accelerate Feynman diagrams will have to be written to show the interaction that accelerates them. Gravitational interactions are very weak. (supposing we have quantized gravity). The electromagnetic interaction is also weak. So the electron(positron) meets its pair and annihilates with some probability. So? There is no chain reaction here. You could treat it as a plasma of electrons and photons, except in time, before this, there would exist the quark gluon plasma, much denser in energy and high in probability of interaction.

For fig C:

It will not repeat eternally. As the [universe expands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanding_universe) the electromagnetic interaction decouples ( the strong one has decoupled before), because the probabilities of interaction become tiny.